# ReplaceAll an Expand repeatedly

Tags: replacement, rule

Is it posible to apply `ReplaceAll` and `Expand` repeatedly such as?

```
expression//.{"substitute", "Expand expression"}
```

A minimal example

```
A B //. {A B -> B (C + D) , B C ->  1} 

(* B(C+D) *)
```

However, I want

```
A B //. {A B -> B (C + D) , B C ->  1} 

(* BC + BD *)
```

and finaly

```
(* 1+BD *)
```

Comment: Note `C` is a protected symbol used to generate integration constants and such. `D` is the differentiation operator.  Generally avoid single capital letters for variables and even beginning variables with capitals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful

```
rules = {A B -> B (C + D), B C -> 1};
expr = A B;
FixedPoint[
  Expand[ReplaceRepeated[#, rules]] &, expr]
```